# Removing "/aura" Logs from Dev Console

Tags: aura, developer-console, console

I have played with the debug levels, but I cannot figure out a way to stop the console from showing all of these annoying "/aura" logs. Has anyone figured out how to remove these?

[image]

Comment: Could you elaborate on why you want to remove them?

Comment: Well, they aren't useful to me, and make it more difficult to view the useful logs. Why do you ask?

Comment: If you are using SF with lightning enabled, this is where a lot of useful logs get captured. Looks like its not useful in your case. I've would have never imagined anybody would want to get rid of those logs or hide them. Anyways, I don't think you can do this at setting level, but you can filter them out. Look at the screenshots I've posted in the answer. May be you were already aware of this.

Comment: Anyone who has 8 useless logs inbetween every useful log would want to get rid of them!

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if there is way to completely stop loading the /aura logs, but you can use the filter box at the bottom of the logs tab. See screenshots below. you can get rid of the other logs just by typing out the operation type you want examine.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks, yes I know, the filter is just limiting because then you can only look at one type of log, and the alternative is to have a ton of aura logs making it difficult to find the others.

Comment: You could post it as an idea here: https://success.salesforce.com/ideaSearch. But, I doubt if there are many salesforce developer looking forward to this feature.